# Why on refreshing my deployed app I get error as "Cannot GET /posts"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making a web application using node and react. I have deployed this app using Heroku.
At the time of development suppose I am at URL `http://localhost:3000/posts`. Now when I refresh the page I am redirected to the same URL.

But after I have deployed my application when I am at URL `https://xyz.herokuapp.com/posts` and try to refresh this page I get a window showing the following message `Cannot GET /posts`.

I am unable to understand this problem of my code or I missed something while deploying it. Please guide me on this problem, also let me know if more information is required.

Comment: I would guess you're missing fall-back/push-state routing in your production deployment, but without a [mre] it's impossible to say.

Comment: having the same problem. did you find an answer to that?